# Effects of China immigration authority canceling my visa

Tags: visa-refusals, china

I went to China on a study visa. The Chinese immigration authority claimed that my documents were fake and they said I was not admissible to China. They cancelled my visa.

On paper they wrote *inadmissible due to fake documents*, but they told me the reason is that some videos in my mobile were not allowed in China. All my documents were original.

I wrote a letter to the Chinese embassy, but they did not answer.

Will I have any problems going to any other country?

Comment: @awais You’ll certainly have a problem trying to get a visa for any country that asks applicants to disclose previous visa refusals, denials of entry etc

Comment: @RoboKaren: Are you sure that's what you intended to link to?

Comment: @RoboKaren: What I get when I follow it is an answer to a question about a refusal of a French study visa, which seems to have essentially nothing to do with this question about a canceled Chinese visa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks, you’re right that I focused on the wrong area of his question. Rescinding dupe flag.

Answer (score 5):

If your question is only:

> My question is will I have any problem to go to any other country?

Then the answer is: Yes, many countries will ask if you’ve ever had a visa denied or revoked before issuing you a visa of their own. You would have to answer in the affirmative and that would make it harder to get your new visa (your documents or travel rationale will be scrutinized more). You also won’t be able to use many visa waiver programs.

But countries realize that immigration in some other countries can be capricious. So it’s not the kiss of death, you’ll just have to apply for visas and make sure your paperwork is complete.

Ps. Don’t even think of lying about a visa revocation as the result of lying and getting found out are pretty terrible.

Comment: China doesn't share these records with anyone. Nobody would know he was "deported for fake documents" if he were to somehow lose his passport. Certainly, the consequences for lying cannot be worse than being inadmissible on fake documents. OP should do what he thinks is best. His version of events is that the Chinese cancelled his visa on false pretenses. Who will the authorities believe?

Comment: @greatone it doesn’t share them now but that isn’t to say China won’t share them in the future. Getting caught lying on immigration forms can lead to lifetime bans and in some cases, getting stripped of naturalization. Not worth the risk.

Comment: Let the OP decide whether or not it's worth the risk. China will never share this information with other countries in our lifetimes unless there is some sort of reciprocal agreement. Do you actually believe that the USA will hand over immigration information to China? Currently, it only shares limited data with the 5-eyes countries who are very close allies. Unless the OP is planning to get naturalized in China, he will not be facing any such issue.

Comment: @greatone ultimately OP has to decide. And things change. We never thought the USA might break from NATO and ally with Russia but it’s now a possibility. China might not share with the USA but it might share with the EU or Australia or Thailand or somewhere else the OP might want to go to. In any case, it’s this forum’s policy that we tell people to never lie. If you don’t like that, you can find another forum or petition to change our policy.

Comment: I'm not telling the OP to lie. But he does not have to disclose his cancelled visa by volunteering that information if not asked. If he were to never submit that passport to the authorities he wouldn't need to lie unless specifically asked about it. Some countries do ask about previous incidents. There, the OP would need to decide which way to go.

Comment: @greatone I say that: don’t proffer info but don’t lie. So he does have to answer questions about previous cancellations truthfully whether in a visa application or when using a visa waiver program that stipulates criteria for eligibility.

Comment: @RoboKaren When China does not give its details to any other country, how will another country know that it has been expelled from China?

Comment: “Oceania was at war with Eurasia, Oceania had always been at war with Eurasia.” - 1984